# Merge multiple arrays together in a specific order?

Tags: c#, arrays

Currently trying to merge some arrays together, I have been given some text files containing years, months and 5 types of weather data (which have been imported as strings, ints and floats depending on the data contained). I now have to display these values showing the year followed by the month and other information.

Now this is the point I am confused as I am unsure on the process of merging these arrays together so the information is all contained together and displaying it but then I also need to search and order it in ascending and descending order whilst retaining information such as the year and month.

Is this something I should be looking to do with arrays or is it more suited to another data structure such as a data table?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a merge sort?

Comment: It look like you need to make a class.  Then parse input data into different properties in the class.  You entire data will be a list collection of the class.

Comment: The sort ordering you describe is a *presentation layer* problem, not necessarily something you want to solve when you initially parse the input

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining a class containing set of strings (with getters and setters)? Try something like this

```
class Data
{
    public string Year{get;set;}
    public string Month{get;set;}
    public string WeatherReport1{get;set;}
    public string WeatherReport2{get;set;}
    public string WeatherReport3{get;set;}
    public string WeatherReport4{get;set;}
    public string WeatherReport5{get;set;}
}
```

Then use this class's objects. Set the value of the Year, Month, WeatherReport1,... . Add the class's objects to the array of this class's type. Somewhat like this

```
class Data
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string WeatherReport1 { get; set; }
    public string WeatherReport2 { get; set; }
    public string WeatherReport3 { get; set; }
    public string WeatherReport4 { get; set; }
    public string WeatherReport5 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data objdata;
        Data[] array = new Data[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            objdata = new Data();
            objdata.Year = "Year";
            objdata.Month = "Month";
            objdata.WeatherReport1 = "report1";
            objdata.WeatherReport2 = "report2";
            objdata.WeatherReport3 = "report3";
            objdata.WeatherReport4 = "report4";
            objdata.WeatherReport5 = "report5";

            array[i] = objdata;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i].Year+" "+array[i].Month+" "+array[i].WeatherReport1+" "+array[i].WeatherReport2+" "+array[i].WeatherReport3+" "+array[i].WeatherReport4+" "+array[i].WeatherReport5);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

I hope it helps. Please let me know. I'm new to StackOverflow and I'm trying to learn new things :)

Comment: `public static string[] WS1_TMax = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Computing\\Downloads\\WS1_TMax.txt");
    public static float[] WS1TmaxInt = Array.ConvertAll<string, float>(WS1_TMax, float.Parse);` Is how i currently import my text files, and i'm just having trouble grasping how i would use those arrays already created inside the new data object? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try your luck with this one please - 

    **class Data
    {
        public string Ws1Tmax{get;set;}
        public float Ws1TmaxInt{get;set;}
    }**
Then you'll have **objdata.Ws1Tmax**. It should be equal to 

**Ws1Tmax=Ws1_TMax[i];**

 and similarly do the same for others. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

depends on the amount of data - and the requirements on what you want to search for. IF they are in any way vague or you have more data then you want in memory / can be arsed figuring out how to store and search then database as its designed to solve these problems - namley how to query data that is stored in a file on a disk.

If it isn't big enough for a database, why are you doing this in code? You are describing something that excel is pretty good at.

This is probably a database job as you could potentially have gigabytes yet only need to present say 20-30 items to a ui at any one time.

As for searching with orders etc you would probably look at an ordered array, then decide you need to key it and then have a comparable key, which would get you to a red black tree or some such. Once you get big enough youd start to look at b tree which basically means use a database.